# Estou tentando imprimir o resultado com uso de axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Estou tentando entender o funcionamento do axios, mas estou enroscado na hora de printar a informação na tela. Consigo visualizar o resultado através do console do navegador e um *undefined* em cima, mas não acho de maneira alguma uma forma de resolver.

Outro problema é que ao invés do resultado, o código mostra todo o conteúdo da função como texto. Onde estou errando?

```js
function titulo() {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.title);
    });
}

titulo();

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Título do post: ' + titulo; //o que inserir aqui para que seja mostrado o title vindo do axios?
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.js"></script>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Clicar para mudar o texto.</p>
```

Comment: O problema é que a requisição é feita de forma assíncrona, daí o código que exibe o texto é executado antes da requisição ser processada, tu teria que realizar o comando dentro do `then` ou usar `async` `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a requisição é feita de forma assíncrona, daí o código que exibe o texto é executado antes da requisição ser processada, tu teria que realizar o comando dentro do `then`ou usar `async`/`await`:

```js
async function titulo() {
  let result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  return result.data.title
}

async function myFunction() {
  let title = await titulo();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Título do post: ' + title; //o que inserir aqui para que seja mostrado o title vindo do axios?
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.js"></script>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Clicar para mudar o texto.</p>
```

Primeiro defina a função com a keyword `async` e ao pegar o resultado da função, utilize o `await` para esperar o processamento

> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma Promise.
>   Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a Promise será resolvida
>   com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou
>   algum valor, a Promise será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão await, que pausa a
>   execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da Promise
>   passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o
>   valor resolvido.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas[Funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou da forma que eu desejo! Ao menos já sei onde me aprofundar nos estudos. Obrigado!